# Compare two dataframes using three columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got two dataframess; df_users like below

[image]

and df1 like below

[image]

I need to create a third dataframe called df2 in which I will get the corresponding usernames from USER_NAME column in df_users by filtering using three columns which are 'InterfaceDesc  TESVLAN  CVLAN'

I tried to use merge, concat and datacompy Compare functions but all failed with different errors occurred. Please support

Comment: look into pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) function

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data not in picture form, and some expected results for df2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the 2 DataFrame only when the columns "InterfaceDesc", "TESVLAN", "CVLAN" are the same, you need to merge the 2 DataFrame on multiple columns and it should work:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df_users, df1, on=["InterfaceDesc", "TESVLAN", "CVLAN"])
```

If you want df2 to have only these 4 columns:

```
df2 = df2[["USER_NAME", "InterfaceDesc", "TESVLAN", "CVLAN"]]
```

Comment: the error appears
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @AhmedTantawy cast these columns to the same datatype